# Defining local settings for title dimension

Tags: sectioning, fontsize

I am writing a paper in LaTeX, and I have to reproduce a template that was given as a .doc file.
So I need to define the dimensions of the chapters titles in Times New Roman 12 pt bold, which is not the default setting in LaTeX.
Can anyone please tell me how to define local settings regarding font and dimension of the text?

p.s. These are my settings

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}%times new roman
\normalfont
\usepackage[round]{natbib} 
parenthesis=[round]
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\graphicspath{{./images/}}
\usepackage{amsmath}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`sectsty`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/sectsty) or [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) packages to set the desired formatting for the sectional unit headings. An example with `sectsty`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{sectsty}

\sectionfont{\fontsize{12}{14.4}\selectfont}

\begin{document}

\section{A test section}

\end{document}
```

An example with `titlesec`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{12}{14.4}\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}

\begin{document}

\section{A test section}

\end{document}
```

Without packages, you can redefine `\section`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
  {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
  {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
  {\normalfont\fontsize{12}{14.4}\bfseries}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{A test section}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is only mimic the Word style, may be you will find simpler start with the `wordlike` package. With the `basic` option typesets section headings in times roman bold and normal size:

```
\documentclass[basic,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{wordlike}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\title{Word-like document}
\author{By a fake Word user}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]